# Hibernate custom schema creation

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

`<prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>` creates a new database schema and `<prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>` create if it is not exists and update existing database schema. If I want to check whether database schema exists or not and depending on that a database schema will be created, how can I achieve this. Currently the configuration of my `applicationContext.xml` is:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>info.ems.models.User</value>
            <value>info.ems.models.Role</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
        </props>
    </property>        
</bean>
<bean id="dao" class="info.ems.hibernate.HibernateEMSDao" init-method="createSchema">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>
```

And the HibernateEMSDao.java:

```
public class HibernateEMSDao implements EMSDao {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    private HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate;

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.hibernateTemplate = new HibernateTemplate(sessionFactory);
    }    

    public void saveUser(User user) {
        hibernateTemplate.saveOrUpdate(user);
    }

    public List<User> listUser() {
        return hibernateTemplate.find("from User");
    }

    public void createSchema() {
        logger.info("inserting default admin user into database");
        User admin = new User();
        admin.setUsername("admin");
        admin.setName("Admin");
        admin.setEmail("admin");
        admin.setPassword("21232f297a57a5a743894a0e4a801fc3");
        saveUser(admin);
        logger.info("Admin inserted into database");

        try {
            System.out.println(listUser().get(0).getId());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("===================Error================");
        }
    }               
}
```

It is working. What configuration will help me to gain this?
Something like:

- Check an user with id=1 exists
- If not create the schema

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could disable the `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` option, check the conditions (probably using plain JDBC) and call (or don't) the [create](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/api/org/hibernate/tool/hbm2ddl/SchemaExport.html#create%28boolean,%20boolean%29) method of the [SchemaExport](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/api/org/hibernate/tool/hbm2ddl/SchemaExport.html) class. This would be done in your application's initialization code (a `ServletContextListener` in case you are working with a web app).

An example on how to use the `SchemaExport` class:

```
AnnotationConfiguration config = new AnnotationConfiguration();
config.addAnnotatedClass(info.ems.models.User.class);
config.addAnnotatedClass(info.ems.models.Role.class);
config.configure();
new SchemaExport(config).create(true, true);
```