# Automatic tool to create schema in MySQL

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I am a Hibernate beginner. I am following "Java Persistence with Hibernate" book and now in chapter 2.

I just found out that in order to test the hello world class, I have to manually create a Messages table in MySQL manually, I found it tedious to type in all the scheme by hand since it is very error-prone.

I wonder if Hibernate has any tool built in that could create a schema for developer automatically? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>` to your hibernate.cfg.xml file and it will do the schema validation for you. If you don't want to override the contents, then do `<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">validate</property>` and it will merely validate it.

Answer (score 1):

Specify `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` in your hibernate configuration. It will create and  drop  database according to your need.

Find out more about this on -

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate can do that. Depending on your setup there are several ways:

- ant: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/toolsetguide.html#toolsetguide-s1-5
- maven: http://mojo.codehaus.org/maven-hibernate3/hibernate3-maven-plugin/

This question has been answered before: 
[Hibernate custom schema creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167474/hibernate-custom-schema-creation)